# Is $\exp(-1/z^2)$ differentiable at $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, limits-without-lhopital

Let $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}: \begin{cases} \exp(-1/z^2) & z \neq 0 \\ 0 & z=0 \end{cases}$ be a function. Is $f$ differentiable in $0$?

Suppose $f$ is differentiable in $a$, then $\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z-0}=\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{\exp(-1/z^2)}{z}$ has to exist in $\mathbb{C}$. I'm not sure how to evaluate this limit. Can I use L'Hopital's rule here or does that only work for real functions?

Comment: you can think of a complex function f(z) as a pair of real functions over the XY plane. $z=x+iy$, $f(z)=U(x,y)+iV(x,y)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try and evaluate the limit where $z \to 0$ along the real line and along the imaginary line. We have

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x} =  0 $$

while

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{-1/(ix)^2}}{ix} = (-i) \cdot \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{1/x^2}}{x} = \infty. $$

The first limit can be calculated using L'Hopital as a real limit or in any other way.

Comment: Here, I treat $\infty$ as a point in the extended plane so that there is no difference between "$+\infty$" and "$-\infty$" but it really doesn't matter. The point is that the limit along the imaginary line, whether you want to think it exists or not, is not the same as the limit along the real line.

Comment: Thank you for your your insight, it's become clear to me now! However, shouldn't it be $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{-1/(ix)^2}}{ix} = \frac{1}{i} \cdot \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{1/x^2}}{x}$?

Comment: The first limit is better computed with $x=1/t$ (for $x>0$, so it becomes $\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{t}{e^{t^2}}=0$ (and similarly for $x<0$).

Comment: @simp $-i=i^{-1}$.

Comment: @egreg Oh okay thanks, I wasn't aware of that yet...

Answer (score 0):

It is infinitely differentiable($\mathcal{C}^\infty$), but not analytic($\mathcal{C}^\omega$).
The first bit is easy to prove by induction, the second bit is easy to prove by looking at that Taylor series at $0$(which is the zero polynomial), which clearly does not converge to the function in any neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: I think that you mean $C^\infty$ and $C^\omega$ instead of $\mathbb{C}^\infty$ and $\mathbb{C}^\omega$. But what is the domain? On $(0,\infty) \subset \mathbb{R}$ what you have stated is true, but not on $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @md2perpe it is in \mathbb{R}, obviously not in \mathbb{C}

Comment: But the question was about differentiability in $\mathbb{C}$.