# Follow-up question to "Differentiablity of $h(x)=\exp(-\frac{1}{x^2})$ for $ x\neq 0$ and $h(0)=0$": How can I show $h(x)\in C^{\infty}$?

Tags: real-analysis

This is a follow-up question to:
[Differentiablity of $h(x)=\exp(-\frac{1}{x^2})$ for $ x\neq 0$ and $h(0)=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4531435/differentiablity-of-hx-exp-frac1x2-for-x-neq-0-and-h0-0)

I want to show: $h(x)\in C^{\infty}$ with
$h(x)=\begin{cases}\exp(-\frac{1}{x^2})& x\neq 0 \\ 0 & x=0 \end{cases}$

Someone before me asked a question like my original question for the first derivative, only for a function $h(z)$ with $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

[Is $\exp(-1/z^2)$ differentiable at $0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2237535/is-exp-1-z2-differentiable-at-0?rq=1)

In the answer from "miraunpajaro" it was stated, that proofing $h(x)\in C^{\infty}$ would be easy and that one could use induction.
$\exp(-\frac{1}{x^2})\in C^{\infty}$ for $x\neq 0$ because the exponential function is infinitely differentiable for every real number.

The statement for $n=1$ is proofed(original question).

Induction assumption [IA]: There is an $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $h^{(n)}(0)=0$

To proof: $h^{(n+1)}(0)$ exists with $h^{(n+1)}(0)=0$

Induction step $n\rightarrow n+1$:
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{h^{(n)}(x)-h^{(n)}(0)}{x-0}\overset{[IA]}{=}\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{h^{(n)}(x)}{x}$$

I proved something like that before, but in that case I could come up with a concrete formula for the $n$th derivative but in this case I find it really hard.

For $x\neq 0$:

$$h'(x)= \frac{2}{x^3}\exp(-\frac{1}{x^2}),\\ h''(x)=(\frac{3!}{x^4}+\frac{4}{x^6}) \exp(-\frac{1}{x^2}),\\h^{(3)}(x)=(\frac{4!}{x^5}+\frac{24}{x^7}+\frac{2}{x^3}h^{(2)}(x)) \exp(-\frac{1}{x^2}),\\
h^{(4)}(x)=(\frac{5!}{x^6}+\frac{24\cdot 7}{x^8}+\frac{3!}{x^4}h^{(2)}(x)+2\frac{2}{x^3}h^{(3)}(x)) \exp(-\frac{1}{x^2})$$

That leads to a really complicated formula...

Is there a simple trick, could there be a theorem I'm not aware of ?Or is it obvious and I just don't see it.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have chosen the wrong inductive claim. One that works better is
$$h^{(n)}(x)=\frac{p_n(x)}{x^{3n}}e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$$
for every $x\neq 0$, where $p_n$ is a suitable polynomial. This one can be shown easily by induction (you just need to calculate a derivative) and it implies that
$$\exists h^{(n)}(0)=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} h^{(n)}(x)=0$$

Comment: $n=1: p_1(x)=2$.
An $n\in \mathbb{N}$ exist, such that $h^{(n)}(x)= \frac{p_n(x)}{x^{3n}}\exp(\frac{-1}{x^2})$. 

$n\rightarrow n+1$:
It follows from the chain-and- product-rule that $h^{(n+1)}(x)$ exists. 
$$h^{(n+1)}(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}x^{-3n-3}(x^3p_n'(x)+p_n(x)(2-3nx^2))$$

$$\lim \limits_{x\to 0} h^{(n+1)}(x)=\lim \limits_{x\to 0}e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}x^{-3n-3}(x^3p_n'(x)+p_n(x)(2-3nx^2))=\lim \limits_{x\to 0}(e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}x^{-3n-3})\cdot\lim \limits_{x\to 0}(x^3p_n'(x)+p_n(x)(2-3nx^2))=0\cdot 0 =0 $$
How can I justify $\lim \limits_{x\to 0}(e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}x^{-3n-3})=0$?

Comment: Just make a change of variable: $t=1/x^2$. The limit becomes (since $x=\pm \sqrt{t}$) $$\lim_{t \rightarrow +\infty}\pm \frac{t^\frac{3n+3}{2}}{e^t}=0$$

Comment: Thanks :) Although I think you meant $x=\frac{\pm 1}{\sqrt{t}}$

Comment: Yes of course, sorry